# Robotframework suitesetup and sockets

Tags: python, robotframework

im trying to test a server application (gdbserver implementation) using Robot framework. My testsuite will test basic command, i.e. step, next, breakpoint et.c. So my idea was to setup the Connection in the suite setup function and then use that Connection in the testcases.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  RSPLibrary.py

Suite Setup  Connect to server

*** Keywords ***
Expect data
    [Arguments]  ${exp}
    ${resp} =  Rec data
    Should be equal as strings  ${resp}  ${exp}

Connect to server
    Connect  127.0.0.1  8080

*** Test Cases ***
Server understands command H
    Send data  Hg-0
    Expect data  OK

Server understands command ?
    Send data  ?
    Expect data  OK
```

My REPLibrary looks like this

```
import socket
import re

class RSPLibrary(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print("RSPLibrary initiated")
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def connect(self, adr, port):
        print("Connect to server")
        self.sock.connect(('localhost', 8080))
        print("Connected to server", self.sock)

    def checksum_str(self, data):
        checksum = sum(bytearray(data, 'utf-8')) % 256
        return hex(checksum >> 4)[2:] + hex(checksum & 0xf)[2:]

    def send_sock(self, data):
        print("Send", self.sock)
        self.sock.send(data)

    def recv_sock(self):
        return self.sock.recv(256)

    def send_data(self, data):
        strToSend = "$" + data + "#" + self.checksum_str(data)
        numResend = 0
        self.send_sock(strToSend)
        while(self.recv_sock() != '+'):
            self.send_sock(strToSend)

    def rec_data(self):
        data = self.recv_sock()
        mo = re.search(r".*\$(.*)\#([0-9a-fA-F]{2})", data)
        (data, checksum) = (mo.group(1), mo.group(2))
        while(self.checksum_str(data) != checksum):
            self.send_sock("-")
            data = self.recv_sock()
        self.send_sock("+")
        return mo.group(1)
```

Problem I have is that I get an error when executing the testcases

> error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

but skipping the suite setup and connecting in the testcase works as expected. I can not figure out why that is the case? How long are the objects created living? The prints of the socket object reports valid objects and not None

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The default scope for a test library is "TEST CASE", meaning the library gets destroyed and recreated for each test case. Since you didn't specify a scope, your library has the default scope. Therefore, each tests gets a fresh instance of the library.

The solution is to explicitly declare that you want the library to exist for the life of the suite rather than the life of each test case so that all test cases share a single socket connection.

```
class RSPLibrary(object):
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST SUITE'
    def __init__(self):
        print("RSPLibrary initiated")
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    ...
```

This is documented in the robot framework user guide, in a section titled [Test library scope](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-library-scope)